# Symfony 4 OneToOne relationship not pulling from database

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4

This issue is so weird!

Example structure of entities relating to each other:

Property
    -> InstructionToSell (OneToOne)
        -> acceptedOffer (OneToOne)

If I do something like:

```
$property = $repo->findOneBy([‘id’=> 1]);
```

It works, all the relationships come back ok.

But now if I create a custom method in the property repo to search postcode with a LIKE query the acceptedOffer relationship is null

It’s confusing me as to why this is happening? It’s the same entity, same relationships, I’m just loading it via a like instead of directly by Id.

Even if I use fetchAll it works fine.

I hope I explained this well enough it’s difficult to explain what I’m seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like "lazy loading" is at work here.

Did you explicitely write the join query in your custom one ? (because maybe you should)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you might have created custom query and when you create them you need to define your joins and select them.

For example;

```php
    $queryBuilder
        ->addSelect('p', 'i', 'o')
        ->join('p.instructionToSell', 'i')
        ->join('i.acceptedOffer', 'o')
        ->setParameter('name', $name)
        ->andWhere(
             $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('p.name', ':name')
        );
```